# How to add cookie on a HttpTransportBindingElement

Tags: wcf, cookies, http-headers

I'm having a **WCF client** which communicates with a **WCF service** (running AspNetCompabilityMode), and I would like to add a **cookie** (on the client) to every call to this web service.

I have looked at the **HttpTransportBindingElement**, but I cannot find where to add my cookie - is it possible to add a cookie to the HttpTransportBindingElement, or should I consider another approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method described in http://kennyw.com/indigo/153 works on a per-service-call basis. This means you have to make sure all invocations to your WCF service are made
**after** the **OperationContextScope** object is created and **before** it is disposed for this to work. Otherwise the cookie will never be added to the request.

If you are looking for a centralized solution to manually add a cookie to all outgoing HTTP requests made to the WCF service have a look at this thread:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/624fb3f9-222d-4795-9140-fe9ef3934361/

Answer (score 3):

http://megakemp.wordpress.com/2009/02/06/managing-shared-cookies-in-wcf/

Unlike other manuals provided in other answers, this one contains all the information you need in one place in a well structured manner.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the allowCookies configuration option for your binding to **false**.  This sounds odd, but it is explained why here:

http://kennyw.com/indigo/211

Once you do that, you have to add the cookies yourself using the method described here:

http://kennyw.com/indigo/153