# Using WCF authentication service for web application

Tags: wcf, web-applications, asp.net-membership

I am using a WCF authentication service I set up with a web application. I have successfully set up and tested the AuthenticationService and RolesService. The web application can successfully call methods like ValidateUser and GetRolesForCurrentUser through the WCF services.

I want to integrate the WCF authentication service with my web.config and site.map. Do I need to write a custom provider, or is there some way I can modify the web.config of the web application to use the WCF authentication service as its membership provider?

This way I can set what roles have access to what directories based off the WCF authentication service.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean Windows Communication Foundation and not the old Windows Foundation Classes (which have nothing to do with ASP.NET).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application Services are not intended as a replacement for the provider stack.

They are meant to augment and enable usage from context other than .aspx.

In most cases you may simply use the default provider stack (Membership/Roles/Profiles).

You simply need to pass the cookies that you get when you call 'Login' via app services around in the context of the service call.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435596/how-to-add-cookie-on-a-httptransportbindingelement) for some more information about adding cookies to a WCF call.

If you are using AJAX to call the services, you don't have to do anything, simply authenticate via ajax and then call via ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Skys answer doesn't seem to answer the question?

It seems to me that there is a genuine need to call the WCF AuthenticationService from an ASP.NET application?

Consider a three tier application where all database access is mandated to be performed by the application tier. There is a single database (data tier) containing business data as well as membership data.

I have written a three tier implementation whereby a custom MembershipProvider on the presentation tier invokes the AuthenticationService on the application tier which in turn runs my custom authentication routine. 
I could quite easily create a custom WCF service (eg not AutheticationService) which does this authentication but I try to use .NET objects where possible. 
it would be nice if I could tell ASP.NET to use the AutheticationService without needing a custom membership provider but I dont think this is possible?