# WCF REST WebHttpBinding cookie handling

Tags: wcf

The problem is WCF client doesn't respect server cookie (doesn't set it on the next request). Here is how I create the client:

```
WebChannelFactory<IPostService> factory = new WebChannelFactory<IPostService>(
    new WebHttpBinding() {AllowCookies = true},
    new Uri("http://10.6.90.45:8081"));

_proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
```

Settings AllowCookies to false has no effect too.

What I did for now is wrote a simple IClientMessageInspector to persist the server cookie between requests, but I really don't want to do this, there should be a way to handle cookie in a standard way.

The custom inspector I'm using now, which is working as expected, but I'm looking for a "clean" solution:

```
  public class CookieInspector : IClientMessageInspector
   {
      private string _cookie;

      public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
      {
         if(_cookie != null && request.Properties.ContainsKey("httpRequest"))
         {
            HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequest = request.Properties["httpRequest"] as HttpRequestMessageProperty;

            if(httpRequest != null)
            {
               httpRequest.Headers["Cookie"] = _cookie;
            }
         }

         return null;
      }

      public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
      {
         if (reply.Properties.ContainsKey("httpResponse"))
         {
            HttpResponseMessageProperty httpResponse = reply.Properties["httpResponse"] as HttpResponseMessageProperty;

            if(httpResponse != null)
            {
               string cookie = httpResponse.Headers.Get("Set-Cookie");

               if (cookie != null) _cookie = cookie;
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to add cookie on a HttpTransportBindingElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435596/how-to-add-cookie-on-a-httptransportbindingelement)
see this page it has complete answer to your question

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't say anything I didn't know. You have to write your own IClientMessageDispatcher which is what I'm using right now. I'm looking for _automatic_ cookie management just like in HttpWebRequest. Server sends a cookie, client accepts the cookie, and sends it back to server on the next request. Usual web model, no special logic. Is that achievable in WCF without custom inspectors?

Comment: i dont have much knowledge about wcf cookies.. i was just reading about it. i read this article http://megakemp.wordpress.com/2009/02/06/managing-shared-cookies-in-wcf/ which may solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this was "fixed" in more recent .NET version (I'm on 4.5), or if the OP had other problems that were keeping this from working, but the allowCookies setting DOES work for this purpose.

It is working for me.... I also have "aspnetcompatabilitymode" set on the server.

```
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpEndpointBinding" allowCookies="true">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
```